# Security Implication of printf(0) in C(Windows)

Tags: c, security

I've noticed in C on Windows platform **printf(0);** can crash any program, since there is no format specifier mentioned in argument.

Usually I've seen it triggers __invoke_watson().

I want to know if there is any security implication associated with this type of scenarios, considering parameter of printf() cannot be controlled attacker.

Comment: Please explain why any developer would call ' printf(0);' ?

Comment: I've found that `*(int*)NULL = 0;` can crash any program, you don't even need `printf`! Or even simpler, so can `abort();`!

Comment: `printf(0); can crash any program, since there is no format specifier mentioned in argument` You are misreading it. If there were no format, then it wouldn't even compile. There _is_ a format, which happens to be the NULL pointer. That is UB, indeed, but not because the format is missing.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got the point. It crashes because NULL DEREFERENCE, Not format specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no security implications here.

`printf(0)` is dereferencing a NULL pointer.  While this will likely make the program crash, there's no room for an attacker to inject anything.

Comment: Crashes in general do constitute a security issue in that they can be used to create denial of service attacks.